# Unable to RTCPeerConnection::setRemoteDescription: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters

Tags: flutter, webrtc, janus-gateway

I keep getting this error on my android webrtc app using the webrtc flutter plugin when I take the sdp from janus-gateway and try to set it as remote description.

I've tried adjusting the sdp cause I thought it wasn't able to parse the string but it didn't work.

```
v=0
o=- 1560396930181938 1 IN IP4 "ip"
s=Mountpoint 99
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE video
a=msid-semantic: WMS janus
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 "ip"
a=sendonlyd
a=mid:video
a=rtcp-mux
a=ice-ufrag:fg6W
a=ice-pwd:wyQGuelBzLh8ToRawNUf9p
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256
a=setup:actpass
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d002a;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AKpY1QPAET8s3AQEBQAAAAwBAAAAKIQ==,aO48gA==
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:3959652904 cname:janus
a=ssrc:3959652904 msid:janus janusv0
a=ssrc:3959652904 mslabel:janus
a=ssrc:3959652904 label:janusv0
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2013266431 "ip" 50391 typ host
a=end-of-candidates
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the "sendonlyd" typo that was already mentioned, pretty sure the cause is the H.264 profile the RTSP camera is setting (since it's a Janus Mountpoint offer, I guess that's what you're doing), which the browser very likely doesn't like. You can override the camera fmtp line using "videofmtp" in Janus. You can find more info on the Janus group, where this is a commonly asked question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/meetecho-janus

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a typo in the SDP:

```
a=sendonlyd
```

should be a=sendonly